# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' phyton3.5.1

Tags: python, urllib

I want to use urllib library using Phynton 3.5.1

Code:

```
import urllib.request
x = urllib.request.urlopen=("https://www.google.com")
print(x.read())
```

After run I got next message :

print(x.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

I am following  next tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GzVNi0oTxQ and previous part is the most simple section. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo

```
import urllib.request
x = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.com")
print(x.read())
```

you had an extra `=` in line 2.